# Executing commands consequtively on multiple folders

Tags: bash, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I have parent folder "parent". Inside this folder I have subfolders, and a file named "names.txt". this file includes the names of these subfolders as follow:

```
Parent_folder
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
.
.
.
.
names.txt
```

The content of the file "names.txt" is as follow:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
.
.
.
```

Inside every folder I have images and I want to apply consecutively 10 scripts on every image ( every script must finish it is job inside every folder, then the second script must be run). `These scripts have different names and they are exist in one folder. I set an environment by sourcing a file then I can call these scripts by its name from terminal` .At the same time I want to apply this process on all the folders at once. i.e. when script #1 is running, I want it to be running on all the folders at the same time. When it is done and script #2 will start. I want it to start in all the folders at once and so on...
In order to achieve this I wrote the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=PATH/TO/THE/PARENT/FOLDER
for i in $(cat $path/names.txt); do
{
script#1
} &
{
script#2
} &
.
.
.

done
```

This code is not working efficiently as all the commands are running at once. I want the commands to run on all the folders at once but consecutively. 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, create a wrapper script that changes to the directory given in the first (and only) command-line argument, performs whatever setup/variable-initialisation/etc it needs, and then runs your 10 scripts in sequence with whatever args they need.

For example, if each script processes all .jpg, .png, and .gif files
in the directory:

```
#! /bin/bash
# example-wrapper.sh

cd "$1"

script1 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script2 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script3 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script4 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script5 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script6 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script7 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script8 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script9 *.{jpg,png,gif}
script10 *.{jpg,png,gif}
```

Next, use `find` to pipe a list of directories into `parallel`.

```
find /path/to/parent/ -mindepth 1 -type -d -print0 | 
  parallel -0 -n 1 ./example-wrapper.sh
```

(the `-mindepth 1` option in `find` excludes the top level directory, i.e. the parent directory itself)

By default, parallel will run one instance (a "job") of `./example-wrapper.sh` for each CPU core you have.  Each instance will get ONE (`-n 1`) directory name.  As soon as a job has finished, another is started (if there are any remaining jobs to run).

This makes maximal use of available CPU power, without letting jobs compete with each other for CPU time.

You can use `parallel`'s `-j` option to tune the number of jobs to run at once.  For CPU-intensive tasks, the default of one job per system core is probably what you want.

If your jobs aren't very CPU-intensive but tend to be more I/O bound, you may want to run 2 or 3 jobs for every core you have (depending on how large your input files are, how fast your storage is, and what kind of devices make up that storage - e.g. SSDs don't suffer from seek latency so won't be slowed down by multiple processes seeking data from all over the disk.  Hard disks do suffer from seek times and WILL slow down from being made to seek randomly all over the place - Linux's disk buffering/caching will help, but won't eliminate the problem).

If you want to get other work done (e.g. normal desktop usage) while these jobs are running, use `-j` to tell `parallel` to use one or two fewer cores than your system has (e.g. `-j 6` on an 8-core system).

NOTE: Tuning parallel processes is a fine art and can take some experimenting to get the best results.

Anyway, from `man parallel`:

> `--jobs N`,
>   `-j N`,
>   `--max-procs N`,
>   `-P N`
>
> Number of jobslots. Run up to N jobs in parallel.  0 means as many as possible. Default is 100% which will run one job per CPU core.
>
> If `--semaphore` is set default is 1 thus making a mutex.

This is really basic and primitive use of `parallel`.  It can do a lot more.  See the man page for details.

BTW, `xargs` also has a `-P` option for running jobs in parallel.  For simple usage like this, it makes little difference whether you use `xargs -P` or `parallel`.  But if your requirements are more complicated, use `parallel`.

`parallel` should be packaged for most linux distros, otherwise it's available from https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 0):

The '&' places your sub-scripts into the background, which is why they're all running at the same time.

What you probably want to do is invert your loops:

```
for script in script1 script2 script3 …; do
    for folder in $(cat $path/names.txt); do
        ( cd $path/$folder; $script; ) &
    done
    wait
done
```

Comment: Note: I leave putting the scripts into your path or generating explicit paths to them as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, What if the scripts have different names?

Comment: The outer loop sets the variable $script to the names of your various scripts in sequence. Or do you mean, what if they have different names in the different folders?

Comment: I don't have scripts inside the folders. I set an environment by sourcing a script to a folder contain these scripts so I can call them whenever I want.

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand your question then. The first line loops through all of the scripts, one by one, assigning their name to the variable "script". Is that not what you wanted? It then executes that script, in parallel, in each folder, and then waits for all of them to complete. Finally, it loops back for the next script in the list.