# running commands consecutively in a bash

Tags: bash

The following bash permits of running the commands 1,2,3 in all the folders that has names included in the file "list.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read i 
do
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
done
```

The commands 1,2,3 in the code are running together in all the folders that has names included in the file "list.txt" . How can the commands run one by one in all the folders (i.e. when the first command finish the second command start and so on...). I tried to use "wait" between the commands but it didn't work!
The solution suggested here [Executing commands consequtively on multiple folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294542/executing-commands-consequtively-on-multiple-folders)
didn't work well! I am looking for another solution

Comment: Don't put them in the background?

Comment: "... didn't work well' ? can you edit you first post and specify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r i #read directory as a raw line
do
    cd "$i"     #cd into the directory
    command1    #run the commands consecutively
    command2
    command3
    cd -        #cd back
done < list.txt
```

If you want to run process all the directories simultaneously (with command1 throught 3 staying consecutive), then replace:

```
    command1   
    command2
    command3
```

with

```
    (
    command1   
    command2
    command3
    )&
```

Comment: Thank you PSkocik. I want command 1 to run in all the folders in the loop. When command 1 is done. The command 2 will start also in all the folders in the loop and so on.

Comment: Just an FYI; `cd -` will return to the previous directory in many shells (eg `bash`, `ksh`) so the `pwd=$PWD` and `cd $pwd` is simpler.

Comment: @goro Oh, I see. Then make it three loops.

Comment: Great!!! that's it . I was looking for it for a while. I highly appreciate your help :)

Comment: FANTASTIC :)))))

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks. It's POSIX even (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), so ultimately portable. I've put it in there.

Comment: The usual way to change working directory for the execution of one or a few commands in a script is to do it in a subshell: `(cd dir && { command; command; command; }& )`. That way you don't have to remember to change back again afterwards.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sometimes I microoptimize computer time. `cd`ing in a subshell is definitely a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `&` to have the next command executed after the previous is finished.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to run them in sequence, but still in the background, and you don't care about the return value of each command, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read i 
do
    { command1; command2; command3; } &
done
```

If you only want `command2` to run if `command1` was successful, you can use `&&`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read i 
do
    command1 && command2 && command3 &
done
```

If you want to run everything synchronously and in the foreground, just remove the `&` altogether:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read i 
do
    command1
    command2
    command3
done
```

Comment: I want command 1 to run in all the folders in the loop. When command 1 is done. The command 2 will start also in all the folders in the loop and so on.

Comment: `{ ... } &` vs `( ... ) &` ?

Comment: `{ ... }` normally doesn't require a subshell, whereas `( ... )` does. But when you put an `&` after it, it might create a subshell anyway--it at least creates a background process.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the remaining commands to be executed only if the previous ones succeeded then the `&&` operator is the way to go.

```
command 1 &&
command 2 &&
command 3
```

then `command 2` will only be run if `command 1` returns 0 (that is succeeds) and `command 3` will only be run if `command 2` returns 0. And that implies that `command 2` waits until `command 1` has finished running.