# Running commands at once

Tags: shell-script, scripting, parallelism

I have text file contain the following commands

```
command1 file1_input; command2 file1_output
command1 file2_input; command2 file2_output
command1 file3_input; command2 file3_output
command1 file4_input; command2 file4_output
command1 file5_input; command2 file5_output
command1 file6_input; command2 file6_output
command1 file7_input; command2 file7_output
................
................
................
................
................
```

I named this file "commands" then I gave it permission using "*chmod a+x*"

I want command 1 to be run, then command 2. Also I want this to be applied on all the files (file1, file2, .... etc) at once. How can I modify the content of this file to do that?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
(
command1 file1_input; command2 file1_output
command1 file2_input; command2 file2_output
command1 file3_input; command2 file3_output
command1 file4_input; command2 file4_output
command1 file5_input; command2 file5_output
command1 file6_input; command2 file6_output
command1 file7_input; command2 file7_output
................
................
................
................
................
)&
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it to run in *parallel* for each `file1..fileN`, but want `commmand1` and `command2` to run in *sequence* for each `fileX`. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294542/170373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the lines as such:

```
(command1 file1_input; command2 file1_output) &
(command1 file2_input; command2 file2_output) &
...
```

And each line will execute its two commands in sequence, but each line will be forked off as parallel background jobs.

If you want the second command to execute only if the first command completed successfully, then change the semicolon to `&&`:

```
(command1 file1_input && command2 file1_output) &
(command1 file2_input && command2 file2_output) &
...
```

Comment: Be aware that this does not scale: You will likely run out of processes or memory if you have a lot of lines.

Answer (score 6):

[GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) does this:

```
$ parallel < /path/to/file/containing/commands
```

The advantage of letting GNU parallel manage the process vs running them all in the background at the same time is that GNU parallel can limit the number of simultaneous jobs to stay within your system's memory and processing capacities, e.g. via `--jobs`, `--load`, `--memfree`, etc.

If you simply run all of the lines in the file simultaneously, you can run your system out of RAM or CPU power, so that it becomes extremely sluggish. Your processes can even begin crashing if your system runs first out of RAM and then out of swap space.